# Confluence Persistence

Tags: java, wiki, confluence

Is there a simple in built way to maintain data in Confluence when writing your own macro? This data needs to be queryable across pages, i.e the user will add the macro to their wiki page. Then this data can be queried by another summary macro.

I have read something about Bandana but I am not sure how to get this to work with my plugin.

Comment: What is Bandana http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=164214

Comment: I tried following the Persistence in Confluence instructions but the Bandana Manager was not injected. I am also not sure how to query the data  in bandana

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully this link can help you on the various options on how to persist data in Confluence: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Persistence+in+Confluence
Sherif

Answer (score 1):

This is a little dated - but my old Twikkir plugin for Confluence makes use of Bandana persistence with a plugin. Some details and a link to the source are here:

http://www.every108minutes.com/2008/06/let-your-confluence-tweet.html

Comment: Any chance of a link to a permanent source or put the code in your response?

Comment: I have updated the link above, but as noted below, it looks like there are better ways of approaching plugin persistence now.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bandana for persistence is no longer recommended. Since Confluence 4.3 there is a new ORM layer available for plugins data persistence - [Active Objects](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/AO/Active+Objects).

Answer (score 0):

If you want query data, you need use a macro {sql}. To use this, you need set the data source at first.